# Multiline python regex fails

Tags: python, regex

I've a string with a mysql structure dump.

```
...
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `contig`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `contig`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `contig` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `seq` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_c
..
```

Now I want to select each string wich contains a create table query.
I tried this with `re.findall` and with several regexes (E.g. `(CREATE TABLE)(.*)[^;]*`)

But each regex I tried returned at best `[('CREATE TABLE', " 'contig' (")]`. But I want the whole query as one element in the list. I tried `rstrip` to remove break lines, but nothing worked.

How can I get each INSERT INTO query as a whole?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not select nested parentheses sequence using regular expressions. So the task you want to perform is unsolvable.

But as a hack, you can try something like this:

```
>>> re.findall('CREATE TABLE[^;]+;', s)
['CREATE TABLE `contig` (...) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;']
```

Part `(.*)` is excess in your regex.